# sql select most recent datetime for each member

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

My brain refuses to cooperate with me today to actually think this through properly so I was hoping to get some feedback:  I want to return a single record from each member for their most recent entrance into the system but so far I obviously have only been able to return a single record for the most recent datetime of any member.  I know the query isn't quite right but my brain refuses to really cooperate...

The SQL:

```
SELECT 
    cm.FNAME, 
    cm.LNAME, 
    cl.entry_access_point, 
    cl.date_entered, 
    cl.res_id, 
    dbo.HourMinuteSecond(cl.date_entered, getUTCDate())[Day:Hour:Minute:Second]
FROM 
    cred.members cm, cred.allocate_log cl
WHERE 
    cm.member_id = cl.member_id AND
    cl.date_exited IS NULL AND 
    cl.evt_id = @eventId AND
    date_entered IN (SELECT max(cl.date_entered)
                     FROM cred.allocate_log cl, cred.members cm
                     WHERE cl.member_id = cm.member_id)
ORDER BY 
    cl.date_entered;
```

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was discontinued with the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (more than **20 years** ago!)

Comment: Well thanks but I'm just kind of trying to get the hang of things.  I'll be working on my join abilities.

Comment: If you're just getting started - learn it properly from the beginning! Don't start getting used to the legacy style - use the **proper ANSI JOINs** always

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add rule for member_id in the subquery:

```
SELECT 
cm.FNAME, 
cm.LNAME, 
cl.entry_access_point, 
cl.date_entered, 
cl.res_id, 
dbo.HourMinuteSecond(cl.date_entered, getUTCDate())[Day:Hour:Minute:Second]
FROM cred.members cm, cred.allocate_log cl
WHERE cm.member_id = cl.member_id AND
    cl.date_exited IS NULL AND 
    cl.evt_id = @eventId AND
    date_entered IN (
        SELECT max(cl.date_entered)
        FROM cred.allocate_log cl, cred.members cms
        WHERE cl.member_id = cms.member_id and cms.member_id = cm.member_id)
ORDER BY cl.date_entered
```

---

But you also need statement for the evt_id in the subquery and it can be simplified like this:

```
SELECT 
    cm.FNAME, 
    cm.LNAME, 
    cl.entry_access_point, 
    cl.date_entered, 
    cl.res_id, 
    dbo.HourMinuteSecond(cl.date_entered, getUTCDate())[Day:Hour:Minute:Second]
    FROM cred.members cm, cred.allocate_log cl
    WHERE cm.member_id = cl.member_id AND
        cl.date_exited IS NULL AND 
        cl.evt_id = @eventId AND
        date_entered >= ALL (
            SELECT cl.date_entered
            FROM cred.allocate_log cls
            WHERE cls.member_id = cm.member_id AND cls.evt_id = cl.evt_id)
    ORDER BY cl.date_entered
```

---

Change the alias for table in the subquery:

```
SELECT 
        cm.FNAME, 
        cm.LNAME, 
        cl.entry_access_point, 
        cl.date_entered, 
        cl.res_id, 
        dbo.HourMinuteSecond(cl.date_entered, getUTCDate())[Day:Hour:Minute:Second]
        FROM cred.members cm, cred.allocate_log cl
        WHERE cm.member_id = cl.member_id AND
            cl.date_exited IS NULL AND 
            cl.evt_id = @eventId AND
            date_entered >= ALL (
                SELECT cls.date_entered
                FROM cred.allocate_log cls
                WHERE cls.member_id = cm.member_id AND cls.evt_id = cl.evt_id)
        ORDER BY cl.date_entered
```

Comment: The first one you gave me worked just fine.  Why would I need the evt_id in the subquery as well?

Comment: Oh wait, probably in case a member_id was found in the subquery that didn't belong to the evt_id in the parent query.  Right?

Comment: Yes, i guess you have a lot of types of events in the log, but you must interested in only one @eventId, right?

Comment: Correct.  Multiple different evt_ids can exist within the log.

Comment: Well, in that case use the second query, it should do just fine :)

Comment: Hmmm.  I would like to say it does but currently the second query is returning me all records for all members, not just the most recent datetime for each member.

Comment: Oh, just a mistake, change an alias to 'cls.date_entered' not the 'cl.date_entered' :) Edited an answer

Answer (score 2):

The best way to do this sort of query is using `row_number()`.  Also, you should learn to use `join` syntax instead of putting joins in the `where` clause.

```
select t.*
from (SELECT cm.FNAME, cm.LNAME, cl.entry_access_point, cl.date_entered, cl.res_id, 
             dbo.HourMinuteSecond(cl.date_entered, getUTCDate()) as [Day:Hour:Minute:Second],
             ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by cm.member_id order by cl.date_enetered desc) as seqnum
      FROM cred.members cm join
           cred.allocate_log cl
           on cm.member_id = cl.member_id
      WHERE cl.date_exited IS NULL AND 
            cl.evt_id = @eventId
     ) t
ORDER BY date_entered;
```

Comment: Alright, I'm not entirely sure what is going on here but I'm trying to pick it apart to understand it better.  I did run this against my db and it is returning more than one record for each member FYI.  Thank you though.

Comment: After studying this for a bit, I'm going to guess you intended for me to use that seqnum at some point to to grab the most recent one so would I be safe in assuming that there is no way to return only the most recent datetime, only a way to sort it?

Comment: I would have accepted this as my answer but Mikhail's response gave me exactly what I was looking for.  Regardless, a +1 to you for showing me a more "modern" way to this in regards to proper joins vs what I did.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

```
select 
   those fields
from cred.members cm,
join (
select member_id, max(date_entered) maxdate
from cred.allocate_log
where date_exited is null
and evt_id = @eventId
group by member_id
) s on cm.member_id = s.member_id
join cred.allocate_log cl on
  cm.member_id = cl.member_id
  and cl.date_entered = s.maxdate
```

you can also use the non-standard `CROSS APPLY` operator which can make things simpler if there might be more than one row with a given date_entered

```
select
   those fields
from cred.members cm
cross apply (
    select top 1
       fields from log
    from cred.allocate_log cl
    where cm.member_id = cl.member_id
    and date_exited is null
    and evt_id = @eventId
    order by date_entered desc
)
```

Comment: I didn't end up checking this out but a +1 for responding, I always appreciate it.